# Can this Ruby code be written more succinctly?

Tags: ruby

```
positions = Hash.new
import_profile.headings.each do |h|
  positions[h.table_name + '.' + h.column_name] = h.position
end
```

Once this is done, the thing I'm interested in is `positions`. This is pretty much exactly how I would write this kind of thing in PHP but I was attracted to Ruby for its `map` and `collect` functions. Is there maybe a one-line way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hash[import_profile.headings.map { |h| ["#{h.table_name}.#{h.column_name}", h.position] }]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the most *succinct* would be something like this.

```
positions = Hash[*import_profile.headings.map do|h|
    [ "#{h.table_name}.#{h.column_name}", h.position ]
  end.flatten
]
```

But that's not terribly readable.  I like your code better.

Comment: You are missing square brackets around the expression in your map. You are also missing a call to `flatten` if you are going to splat the result. This code does not even pass a syntax check.

Comment: You're right.  I was thinking I didn't need flatten with the splat operator.  I also just forgot to add the square brackets when I copied from the other machine.

Comment: `.map.flatten(1)` == `.flat_map`

Answer (score 2):

```
positions = Hash[ import_profile.headings.map do |h|
  [ "#{h.table_name}.#{h.column_name}", h.position ]
end ]
```

or

```
positions = Hash[ *import_profile.headings.map do |h|
  [ "#{h.table_name}.#{h.column_name}", h.position ]
end.flatten ]
```

The former only works in Ruby 1.8.7+, where `Hash.[]` is allowed to receive an array of two-value arrays. The latter works in earlier versions, where `Hash.[]` was only allowed to receive an even number of parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested, this is how `inject` based solution would look like. Not shorter, but a bit more FP-ish:

```
positions = import_profile.headings.inject({}) do |acc,h|
  acc["#{h.table_name}.#{h.column_name}"] = h.position
  acc
end
```

Comment: Or acc.merge{"#{h.table_name}.#{h.column_name}" => h.position} , to get rid of the last 'acc'

Comment: Yup. I always hated lack of Hash assignment method which would return the hash itself. :(

Comment: @steenslag The problem with that is that you would be creating a new hash each iteration. Better to use `merge!`. Not that it is very inefficient, though.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of joining the words together is to use `join`:

```
positions = Hash.new
import_profile.headings.each do |h|
  positions[[h.table_name, h.column_name].join(".")] = h.position
end
```